# How to compare if a number is smaller than 10 of the second number

Tags: linux, bash

How can I check if the number $A is at least 10 smaller than number $B in bash?

```
 [[ $A  . . . $B ]] && echo “$A value at least 10 smaller than $B number”
```

For example, if `A=5` and `B=16`, then it will print the line:

```
 5 value is at least 10 smaller than 16 number
```

Comment: As a native speaker of English, I have to admit that I have no idea what "$A Value is grow in 10 number then $B number" means.  Can you try a different wording?

Comment: Are you trying to find out whether a given number is more than 10 smaller than another number? i.e If `A+10 < B` is true?

Comment: yes I mean that , and sorry for my bad English -:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean I'm no expert but if you're checking to see if $A is at least 10 greater than $B you can do:

```
[ $A -gt $((B+10)) ] && echo “$A Value is grow in 10 number then $B number”
```

Comment: Based on his comment, he meant it the other way around : `[(($A+10)) - lt $B]`